# Apply strategies in a directory

Tags: ruby

I'm developing a Sudoku solver using "human" methods.

I have a list of strategies in a `lib/strategies` directory and they all work the same, that's to say like this `StrategyName.new(sudoku).apply`

How do I automatically apply all the strategies in the directory in the order I choose ? I can make each strategy give an ID to return its position in the strategy list for instance, or register them all in the right order in the solver class. But how do I list them all and apply them ? (autoload is on)

Thank you in advance !

Comment: You mean something like `SN.new(SN.new(sudoku).apply).apply` ... ?

Comment: @Dogbert, look up the strategy design pattern.  It's typically a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your files follow the typical typical naming convention:

```
Dir[File.expand_path("../strategies/*.rb", __FILE__)].each do |f|
  name  = File.basename(f, ".rb")
  klass = name.capitalize.gsub(/(_([a-z]))/) { |c| c[1].upcase }
  @strategies << const_get(klass).new(sudoku)
end

@strategies.sort_by! { |s| s.priority }
```

Assuming each strategy has a `#priority` method.

```
@strategies.each { |s| break if s.apply }
```

Comment: You might also need to `require f`, though you say autoloading is on.

Comment: Used Activerecord `constantize` instead of `const_get` (needs to be wrapped into a Module). Thank you for the great snippet !

Comment: No problem! If you're in a Rails application, there's also a method for converting the underscore string into a camel-case string. `name.camelize` in the above, rather than the gsub thing: `@strategies << File.basename(f, ".rb").camelize.constantize.new(..)`.

Comment: Was Activesupport not Activerecord. I'm outside of Rails but thank you :